# Remove rows entirely duplicated, leaving only one of them

Tags: sql-server-2005

Please suppose that I have a table with a certain, unspecified number of columns.

I would like to delete the rows entirely duplicated, this means the rows which have all the columns matching in equality, leaving out the duplicated and keeping only 1 row.

How could I achieve this?

Example: SQL Server 2005, table with 5 columns `FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4, FIELD5`:

```
5   3   2   A   J
3   5   2   A   J
5   3   2   A   J
5   3   2   A   J
8   B   8   A   K
```

The first row, the third row and the fourth row are duplicates, so you have to leave in the table only one of them.

Comment: You might consider adding `SQL` and `SQL-SERVER` tags to attract wider audience :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might employ [row_number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to assign numbers to duplicates and delete where `rn` is greater than one (single occurrance or first duplicate).

A small test, since Sql Fiddle is not available ATM:

```
declare @t table (FIELD1 varchar(10), FIELD2 varchar(10), FIELD3 varchar(10), FIELD4 varchar(10), FIELD5 varchar(10))

insert into @t values ('5', '3', '2', 'A', 'J')
insert into @t values ('3', '5', '2', 'A', 'J')
insert into @t values ('5', '3', '2', 'A', 'J')
insert into @t values ('5', '3', '2', 'A', 'J')
insert into @t values ('8', 'B', '8', 'A', 'K')

; with g as (
  select *,
         row_number() over (partition by field1, field2, field3, field4, field5 
                            order by (select null)) rn
    from @t
)
delete g
where rn > 1

select *
from @t
```

The downside is that you have to specify all columns. If you want to aviod this, and your table does not have foreign keys and is not referenced by any you might insert `DISTINCT` data into temporary table, `TRUNCATE` original and reinsert from temporary table.

Comment: OK, but the temporary table requires space to be created, so in some cases it is not possibile, if the production environment has not enough space to create it.  It is also possible you haven't sufficient privileges to create a new table.  Thank you for your code ;-)